# Custom Rearrange Package View Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I am working on java using IntelliJ. I have some sub-packages in src package. I want to rearrange according to my own. Like in src package I have two sub packages stack & other is queue. I have made Stack first and queue later. But I think they have been sorted alphabetically that is why queue is appearing before stack. How can I change or rearrange according to my own.

Comment: Does `Sort by Type` on Project Explorer help here?

Comment: How to perform this action?

Comment: Go to Project tab on Side Bar. Select settings icon and then sort by type.

Comment: @nullpointer Not Worked

Comment: Ya even I thought so, wouldn't work. Would await an answer then.